# Ftrjsdk-dll (32 bit) does not load on a AMD 64-bit platform

Tags: eclipse, dll, 32-bit

I have read some links about Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform, but could not understood what to do properly.
I am running eclipse on 64 bit operating system and installed jdk 64 which gives the above error.

As i cannot run this 32 bit dll ,so i installed jre 32 bit but it does not let me open eclipse with error code 13.

I also tried giving alternate path to jre but it gives error no ftrJSDK.dll in build path.

so what should i do, how to properly install and make it work.

Comment: Run Eclipse 64 bit on 64 bit Java and in _Window > Preferences: Java > Installed JREs_ configure a 32 bit Java JRE/JDK which is used to run your Java application.

Comment: yes i did that it says no dll in build path.

Comment: In _Project > Properties: Java Build Path_, in the tab _Libraries_ expand the JAR node, select the subnode _Native library location_ and hit the _Edit..._ button on the right. In this dialog, you have to specify the directory that contains the DLL.